# Listing nodes using jclouds

Tags: amazon-ec2, jclouds

Is it possible to list nodes in a non-default AWS VPC? This can be done easily using EC2::DescribeInstances by passing a filter with vpc-id= but I can't figure out how to do it using jclouds.

I know how to create an instance in a specified VPC using template options, but I cannot find an equivalent approach for listing nodes. I'm currently using listNodesDetailsMatching(...).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot eagerly filter that on the provider. Using the portable interface you can just provide a predicate to filter nodes once you have them all. You can directly use the underlying AWS EC2 API to do what you want. It could be something like the following:

```java
AWSEC2Api aws = computeServiceContext.unwrapApi(AWSEC2Api.class);
AWSInstanceApi instanceApi = aws.getInstanceApi().get();
instanceApi.describeInstancesInRegionWithFilter("region", ImmutableMultimap.of("vpc-id", "myvpc"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Ignasi. I was already filtering on the client side, but was not happy with the performance (EC2 call taking too long to return and process). Thanks for confirming that eager filtering was not possible in this case with jclouds (although it is possible with direct access to the EC2 API).